# How to pull layers one by one in Docker to avoid connection timeout?

Tags: docker

I keep getting connection timeout while pulling an image:

[image]

First, it starts downloading the 3 first layers, after one of them finish, the 4th layer try to start downloading. Now the problem is it won't start until the two remaining layers finish there download process, and before that happens (I think) the fourth layer fails to start downloading and abort the whole process.
So I was thinking, if downloading the layers one by one would solve this problem. 
Or maybe a better way/option to solve this issue that may occure when you don't have a very fast internet speed.

Comment: I don't think you can download docker images from browser. Maybe there is a command to `resume` the download?

Comment: Yeah, I wish/hope there is one. And the biggest problem is even if 9/10 of the layers finished (and even get extracted), if the 10th layers fails, you'll have to download again all of them again (including all the already finished ones).

Comment: It seems there is an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12823) for that . Also, this SO question: [How to resume downloading image when interrupted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315735/docker-how-to-resume-downloading-image-when-interrupted)

Comment: `--max-concurrent-downloads` solved the timeout problem so, I can can rely on it till they implement a better download management.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Docker daemon has a `--max-concurrent-downloads` option.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), it sets the *max concurrent downloads for each pull*.

So you can start the daemon with `dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads 1` to get the desired effect.

See the [dockerd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) for how to set daemon options on startup.

Answer (score 30):

Please follow the step if docker running already Ubuntu:

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads 1
```

Download your images after that stop this terminal and start the daemon again as it was earlier.

```
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 ways:

1. permanent change. add docker settings file:

sudo vim /etc/docker/daemon.json

the json file as below:

{
"max-concurrent-uploads": 1,
"max-concurrent-downloads": 4
}

after adding the file, run
sudo service docker restart

2. temporary change

stop the docker by

sudo service docker stop

then run

sudo dockerd --max-concurrent-uploads 1

at this point, start the push at another terminal. it will transfer files one by one. when you finished, restart the service or computer.

Answer (score -1):

Building on the previous answers, in my case I couldn't do `service stop`, and also I wanted to make sure I would restart the docker daemon in the same state, I thus followed these steps:

1. Record the command line used to start the docker daemon:

   ```
    ps aux | grep dockerd
   ```
2. Stop the docker daemon:

   ```
    sudo kill <process id retrieved from previous command>
   ```
3. Restart docker daemon with `max-concurrent-downloads` option: Use the command retrieved at the first step, and add `--max-concurrent-downloads 1`

**Additionally**

You might still run into a problem if even with a single download at a time, your pull is still aborted at some point, and layers that are already downloaded are erased. It's a bug, but it was my case.

A solution in that case is to make sure to keep already downloaded layers, voluntarily.

The way to do that is to regularly abort the pull manually, but NOT by killing the `docker` command, but BY KILLING THE DOCKER DAEMON.

Actually, it's the daemon that erases already downloaded layers when the pull fails. Thus, by killing it, it can't erase these layers. The `docker pull` command does terminate, but once you restart the docker daemon, and then relaunch your `docker pull` command, downloaded layers are still here.