# dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads 1 command not found

Tags: docker

I was trying to use the suggestions int he comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303784/how-to-pull-layers-one-by-one-in-docker) in order to pull one image layer at a time.

Per the discussion on that post I typed:

```
dockerd --max-concurrent-downloads 1
```

Which gave

> bash: dockerd: command not found

I'm using Docker Toolbox since I'm on a old Mac.

I tried looking for a directory /etc/docker too since that came up in the comments on the linked post but this directory does not exist in my hierarchy.

Since I'm using Docker Toolbox I'm apparently using a VM.

My docker info below.

How can I configure to only download one layer at a time when using run or pull?

```
Macs-MacBook:~ macuser$ docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.09.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.116-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 18.09.6 (TCL 8.2.1)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.951GiB
Name: default
ID: XMCE:OBLV:CKEX:EGIB:PHQ7:MLHF:ZJSA:PGYN:OIMM:JI67:ETCI:JKBH
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```