# Is "docker pull" supposed to re-use already downloaded layers instead of starting from scratch?

Tags: docker

I need to [`docker pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) a quite big image, and it's sometimes failing in the middle of the process.

Unfortunately, layers already downloaded successfully are re-downloaded again when I try to resume the download. This makes it impossible for me to retrieve the image.

[image: docker pull]

Here is the output of the `docker version` command:

```sh
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 11:56:38 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:54:50 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc95
  GitCommit:        b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Dockerd logs:

```sh
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:39.754978716+02:00] Calling HEAD /_ping                          
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:39.755344873+02:00] Calling GET /v1.41/info                      
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:39.763731573+02:00] Calling POST /v1.41/images/create?fromImage=python&tag=latest 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:39.774965899+02:00] Trying to pull python from https://registry-1.docker.io v2 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:40.924845790+02:00] Pulling ref from V2 registry: python:latest  
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:40.924924974+02:00] docker.io/library/python:latest resolved to a manifestList object with 10 entries; looking for a unknown/amd64 match 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:40.924952078+02:00] found match for linux/amd64 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:736b76eb3f64778646ce0051fb5fed4dfbf67016e51563946230ca8bb40ac687 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:40.929473526+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:4c25b3090c2685271afcffc2a4db73f15ab11a0124bfcde6085c934a4e6f4a51" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:40.929619687+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:b95c0dd0dc0d3d367cc5b85f86d8881afb658e8eb341a86daf3835c2f14159ac" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:40.929669326+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:1acf565088aae3ef2159885f29853bce88eb16082b0c98fcacd08fc9008c84b9" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:41.796410803+02:00] Downloaded 1acf565088aa to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob363592721 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:41.796450271+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:5cf06daf65610482c638dcc63479a8281e667e37f7842219d66f2dedf63718f4" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:44.848974822+02:00] Downloaded b95c0dd0dc0d to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob588912378 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:44.849016058+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:942374d5c11438b68e78d44b36c9eac8fe0a2570c33681d7263b0f3f069c06b9" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:45.306326372+02:00] Downloaded 5cf06daf6561 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob051180092 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:45.306370914+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:64c0f10e4cfa269d154d1eb6cacfe7f80c8752cdba00f38e25b0cb19dc7cc34a" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:46.302436324+02:00] Downloaded 64c0f10e4cfa to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob795001550 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:46.302481305+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:76571888410befe61a75dd27d009038714785fa5ccb4bdadfede174d14949e3d" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:48.166901123+02:00] Downloaded 76571888410b to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob739185109 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:48.166947530+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:5e88ca15437b3dc8d05eeaf131cafadcf3cfa5cecf2983527f881ba1f67b84c3" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:48.653405031+02:00] Downloaded 5e88ca15437b to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob149809968 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:48.653452783+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:0ab5ec7719940ff567e31ea7bcb202c5a70cf97551c77fd8a9ffcffe8d8c6a57" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:49.424068702+02:00] Downloaded 0ab5ec771994 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob318684879 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:49.426141987+02:00] Downloaded 4c25b3090c26 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob454893639 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:49.426207187+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:49.426399582+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/b1e9aaebbb54388ce06abfda786117e2f538bedb1d618a885dcb093c9e2f409f/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.280665873+02:00] Applied tar sha256:a881cfa23a7842d844818a1cb4d8460a7396b94fdc0bc4091f8d79b8f4f81c3e to b1e9aaebbb54388ce06abfda786117e2f538bedb1d618a885dcb093c9e2f409f, size: 123864207 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.353532429+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.353869276+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a2ccc41a1537fe12f0c5d96286b7b798ff2c484ac6f11824dcf3981686be983/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.562308975+02:00] Applied tar sha256:05103deb4558d56fd1de73608ad22550a54dbefb0d47075f0c3befd2ed7d66e4 to 9a2ccc41a1537fe12f0c5d96286b7b798ff2c484ac6f11824dcf3981686be983, size: 10684871 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.604688305+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.604975593+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/833ad068e1c3ab693549695e5f6d22daa54fbce4780a33eb353300c539830a5f/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.883768452+02:00] Applied tar sha256:21b17a30443eda5d88894fada42fb1e4e1de37047047a4efca67cd52dfb577ac to 833ad068e1c3ab693549695e5f6d22daa54fbce4780a33eb353300c539830a5f, size: 18947183 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.924440066+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:51.924783429+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a99515ca604031cebf0df3e510b226095bd1e899c56549f5db409e407ac80e78/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2021-08-19T14:06:52.703202766+02:00] Not continuing with pull after error: context canceled 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:52.724819509+02:00] Cleaning up layer a99515ca604031cebf0df3e510b226095bd1e899c56549f5db409e407ac80e78: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:56.328416130+02:00] Calling HEAD /_ping                          
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:56.328705545+02:00] Calling GET /v1.41/info                      
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:56.337972066+02:00] Calling POST /v1.41/images/create?fromImage=python&tag=latest 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:56.353551602+02:00] Trying to pull python from https://registry-1.docker.io v2 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:57.476373591+02:00] Pulling ref from V2 registry: python:latest  
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:57.476407362+02:00] docker.io/library/python:latest resolved to a manifestList object with 10 entries; looking for a unknown/amd64 match 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:57.476415889+02:00] found match for linux/amd64 with media type application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, digest sha256:736b76eb3f64778646ce0051fb5fed4dfbf67016e51563946230ca8bb40ac687 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:57.482186100+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:4c25b3090c2685271afcffc2a4db73f15ab11a0124bfcde6085c934a4e6f4a51" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:57.482226533+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:1acf565088aae3ef2159885f29853bce88eb16082b0c98fcacd08fc9008c84b9" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:57.482203515+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:b95c0dd0dc0d3d367cc5b85f86d8881afb658e8eb341a86daf3835c2f14159ac" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:58.238783736+02:00] Downloaded 1acf565088aa to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob073793403 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:58.238832566+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:5cf06daf65610482c638dcc63479a8281e667e37f7842219d66f2dedf63718f4" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:59.257317715+02:00] Downloaded b95c0dd0dc0d to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob251369630 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:06:59.257376537+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:942374d5c11438b68e78d44b36c9eac8fe0a2570c33681d7263b0f3f069c06b9" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:03.820091275+02:00] Downloaded 5cf06daf6561 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob836805477 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:03.820193220+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:64c0f10e4cfa269d154d1eb6cacfe7f80c8752cdba00f38e25b0cb19dc7cc34a" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:04.962753060+02:00] Downloaded 64c0f10e4cfa to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob929255135 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:04.962794668+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:76571888410befe61a75dd27d009038714785fa5ccb4bdadfede174d14949e3d" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:06.712898123+02:00] Downloaded 76571888410b to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob578879666 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:06.712943994+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:5e88ca15437b3dc8d05eeaf131cafadcf3cfa5cecf2983527f881ba1f67b84c3" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:07.157176828+02:00] Downloaded 5e88ca15437b to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob330998377 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:07.157232136+02:00] pulling blob "sha256:0ab5ec7719940ff567e31ea7bcb202c5a70cf97551c77fd8a9ffcffe8d8c6a57" 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:07.938382550+02:00] Downloaded 0ab5ec771994 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob812117172 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:11.522357048+02:00] Downloaded 4c25b3090c26 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob080094604 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:11.522435782+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:11.522668074+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/db0715b3dae57062be8f56229b503be45cb059990ef05a1ac1f5d9989038a16c/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.206092972+02:00] Downloaded 942374d5c114 to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob821111680 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.380850399+02:00] Applied tar sha256:a881cfa23a7842d844818a1cb4d8460a7396b94fdc0bc4091f8d79b8f4f81c3e to db0715b3dae57062be8f56229b503be45cb059990ef05a1ac1f5d9989038a16c, size: 123864207 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.436868371+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.437673910+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ae0cf14f9135fbb814c902503b843c43c475dea695aba22295292a577357b83/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.650565770+02:00] Applied tar sha256:05103deb4558d56fd1de73608ad22550a54dbefb0d47075f0c3befd2ed7d66e4 to 3ae0cf14f9135fbb814c902503b843c43c475dea695aba22295292a577357b83, size: 10684871 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.695301827+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.695622090+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5163db311ab573975124b347f55445c45930ea7da36459f061cf2c933f65e80b/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:13.966606917+02:00] Applied tar sha256:21b17a30443eda5d88894fada42fb1e4e1de37047047a4efca67cd52dfb577ac to 5163db311ab573975124b347f55445c45930ea7da36459f061cf2c933f65e80b, size: 18947183 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:14.008149799+02:00] unpigz binary not found, falling back to go gzip library 
DEBU[2021-08-19T14:07:14.008542144+02:00] Applying tar in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/6c44cbb4566a60b1284c0d301072c7eec05f9759de3c67487333eab61248e45f/diff  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2021-08-19T14:07:14.352489968+02:00] Not continuing with pull after error: context canceled
```

I was thinking according to this answer that Docker should not re-download previously downloaded layers: [Docker. How to resume downloading image when interrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315735/docker-how-to-resume-downloading-image-when-interrupted)

Does anyone know why it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Looks like your docker build cache is getting cleared. or it can't write to `/var/lib/docker`? Do you have an alias for `--no-cache` for the command? can you [edit] and upload a screencapture oif runing the same commands, this time `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` prefixed to the commands or exported?

Comment: Actually never mind, I can repro the same. probably a bug

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Thanks for trying to reproduce it. Actually, I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature not yet implemented (see this opened Github issue: [cancelling a pull causes partially or fully downloaded layers to be discarded](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26146)).

Comment: yeah and that is linked to https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/38738 which is still in draft.. added a vote

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found a workaround.

Instead of killing the `docker pull` command, if you kill the `dockerd` process, it won't delete intermediate layers.

The `docker pull` command will exit obviously, but if you then restart the daemon, and then relaunch your `docker pull` command, previously downloaded layers are there