# Is it possible to pull docker images in a resumable fashion?

Tags: docker

Sometimes my internet connection gets slow and unstable. And when I use `docker pull image_name_here` for images that are large in volume, I see that they get stuck in the middle of the download process. Or the internet connection is lost and it times out or exist with other errors.

But when I execute that pull command again, the layers that are already downloaded won't be  saved on my drive. They would be downloaded again.

This means for large images on an unstable network I literally can't pull the image.

Is there a way for me to somehow resume the pull process from where it was interrupted.

Is there a third party app that does that?

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu & Debian)

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315735/docker-how-to-resume-downloading-image-when-interrupted) docker should resume downloads automatically. Are you sure you're seeing completed layers downloading again?

Comment: Try the experimental feature: --features='{"containerd-snapshotter": true}'
But consider that switching to containerd snapshotters causes you to temporarily lose images and containers created using the classic storage drivers. https://docs.docker.com/storage/containerd/

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
and add the extra dictionary element "features":

Assuming there exist some elements already like `runtime`, add the `features` as of the below:

```
{
    "runtime": { ......... 
    },
   "features": {
       "containerd-snapshotter": true
   }
}
```

Finally, restart the Docker daemon for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This feature is built to allow snapshotting and I've enabled it and it's working :D https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1187#issuecomment-1457279396